# How to test opening new tab with Jasmine in Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jasmine

I'm building chrome extension and I'm having some trouble getting tests to work the way I'd like them to.  I access this page by simply going to extension url ending tests.html.

Let's say I want to test the following very simple scenario: new tab is opened in chrome and it is loaded, this event is detected by my extension, new tab is added to array of tabs within my apps. I have all my Jasmine tests in a separate extension page.

I tried the following things, and they all fail.

One, trying to call Jasmine "expect" with some Timeout (needed for loading the page).

```
describe("Tab collection", function () {
    it("after opening new tab it should be in app.tabs", function () { 
        chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.com"});
        setTimeout(function () {
            expect(app.tabs.length).toBe(1);
            console.log("app.tabs.length after timeout", app.tabs.length);
        },100);
    });
```

Console.log does not log anything, tests is green, even tough clearly it wasn't run.

Two, trying to run 'expect' in chrome.tabs.create callback function.

```
    it("after opening new tab it shoule be in app.tabs", function () {
        chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.com"}, function () {
            expect(app.tabs.length).toBe(1); //
            console.log("app.tabs.length in callback to chrome.tabs.create",app.tabs.length); 
        })
    });
});
```

Console.log logs 0, but for some reasons test passes. Why it passes if app.tabs.length is 0?

Third scenario involves running all my tests after opening new chrome tab. Something along the lines

```
chrome.tabs.open({some_url},function (tab) {
    execJasmine()
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab['id'])
})
```

this works, but is extremely inconvenient, all my tests now run with this open tab. It doesn't really allow me to test things.

Fourth I tried to do this with Jasmine BeforeEach

```
beforeEach(function () {
    chrome.tabs.create(some_url);
});
```

This is closest to being ok, but now the tests fails, app.tabs.length is 0, because the page is not yet loaded when the test suite is called.

Has anyone encountered simlar problems? How can I test described scenario?

Comment: (BTW, since the 2.x version is introducing some significant changes, make sure to mention the version you are using when asking Jasmine-related question.)

Comment: how do you run this tests? How does it have acces to chrome.tabs.create? I'm looking a way to test my extension too. :) I've been trying to use phantomjs, but it is not chrome based as far as I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is synchronous. You have to declare a second parameter in the callback of `it` to make your test asynchronous:

```
describe("Tab collection", function () {
    it("after opening new tab it should be in app.tabs", function(done) {
        //                                                        ^^^^
        chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.com"}, function() {
            expect(app.tabs.length).toBe(1);
            console.log("app.tabs.length after timeout", app.tabs.length);
            done(); // <------
        });
    });
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Ok, tests passes, but console logs value of 0, is it because call to console.log takes place before expect is executed?

Comment: @Pawelmhm No, "app.tabs.length" is a number, so its value is not lazily evaluated by `console.log`. If you're seeing inconsistent results, then your method of setting up `app.tabs.length` might be flawed.

Comment: @Pawelmhm: One more thing to check: How/when you add tabs to `app.tabs` may also paly a role. The callback of `chrome.tabs.create()` is executed once the tab has been created, but that does not tell you anything about the status of the tab. Depending on how/when you add a new tab in your `app.tabs` list, the callback could be executed before the new tab is detected and added to the list.